# Mongodb aggregate lookup for merged collections?

Tags: mongodb, go

Merged queries takes more time for requests, for instance having a username query from user collection and having a query from productpost, costs server process power with more requests sent from userend.

My Q is  can we have aggregate function for the latest golang mongodb integration?

Comment: Measure and see. It depends on the available indexes and the database structure. If the indexes are right, aggregate is likely to be faster. Aggregation does not make unnecessary searches.

Comment: In general, aggregate lookup is a single call, runs on the database server and returns a  result. This is likely to be efficient than multiple calls - the network time is reduced, for example. The aggregate query can be as efficient as you can build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much time spent on this. The easiest way to do this is via requests than lookups since it will require to go through all documents to find:

Here is mongodb document structure

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6198b5cf985bb6b616480463"},"userid":{"$oid":"613dfcca9e7e2014c12dfeef"},"attach":"[\"https://image.bitfinicon.com/be/images/2021/10/OTKAR2021-10-0222-40-33_5877034727566088.png\"]","title":"I'm title here"}
```

Then in the JS you call requests (Using Sveltekit new generation):

```
<div class="author-name">
            <!-- DONEAPPLYCHANGES DONE ALDOLAP -->
            {#if config.name === 'aldolap'}
                <div class="author-name-prefix">{product.price} TL</div>
            {/if}
                {#await getuserhere2(product.userid)}
                    <p>...waiting</p>
                {:then number}
                <a href={`/u/` + number.username + `_` + `${product.userid}`} >{number.username}</a>
                    
                {:catch error}
                    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
                {/await}
        </div>
```